# install angular library - unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular-library

Some time ago I've pulled my generic code from my angular application into libraries. Now it seems that I'm unable to install a library targetting `@angular/core@13.1` into a newly created application which also targets 13.1.

Library [`package.json`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-animations/package.json)

```
{
  "name": "@xxx/ng-animations",
  "private": false,
  "version": "13.1.3",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Brand new application `package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Somehow this causes the following version conflict error which I'm unable to resolve (I resolved some of these in the past)

```
npm i @mintplayer/ng-animations
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tada@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^13.1.0" from @mintplayer/ng-animations@13.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mintplayer/ng-animations
npm ERR!     @mintplayer/ng-animations@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/animations)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"13.1.2" from @angular/common@13.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.1.0" from @mintplayer/ng-animations@13.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mintplayer/ng-animations
npm ERR!     @mintplayer/ng-animations@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I'm on the latest version of angular:

```
> ng version

Angular CLI: 13.1.3
Node: 14.18.2
Package Manager: npm 8.3.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.1.3
@angular/cli                    13.1.3
@schematics/angular             13.1.3
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.4

> node -v
v14.18.2

> npm -v
8.3.0
```

I had a similar problem some time ago, but that was when I was upgrading my application from angular 11 to 13, and I was able to solve it by checking the versions of the specific package npm was complaining about. But now all versions are the same (13.x.x or 13.1.x).

Everything is targetting angular 13.1, so where does this error come from? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your global verson is the latest but not the project version.
run `npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13` inside the project and the install the dependency again

another option is to install the library it with `--force` flag

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it says `Package '@angular/core' is already up to date.` (same for @angular/cli). I created my test project just now too

Comment: strange, your dependencies should look like this:
`   "@angular/animations": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "13.1.1",
`
maybe you can try to edit package.json manually, and the delete node_modules folder and run `npm install`

Comment: So the application package.json should not contain version quantifiers (`^` or `~`)? I was doubting already by comparing both package.json files...

Comment: When I add my dependency to package.json without quanitfier (`"13.1.3"`) I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: i think it should not matter much. (i am not an expert in this matter)
I forgot to told you to delete package-lock.json.

without package-lock.json it will install the exact version

Comment: Indeed,  with all `@angular` packages versioned to `13.1.1` (without quantifier), I'm in fact able to run `npm install` without conflicts, or `--force`... However with other applications I do have `^` and `~` in my package.json, also with custom libraries (or perhaps they shouldn't be there either?). So why would it be different here?

Comment: Ah it does work when I use the minor-version specifier in my application package.json: `"@example/ng-animations": "~13.1.3"`. `npm i` always uses `^` and seems to fail because of this...

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install @angular/service-worker, however it showed me a similar issue, what I did was:

- Delete the node_modules package
- Then run `npm update` instead of `npm install`

The version of my package @angular/service-worker was already on package.json before running the command `npm update`.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution I used to fix the same issue:

Step 1) npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
Step 2) npm i
Step 3) npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations --save